# Wiring up Docker Compose Prometheus with bare ASP.NET Core Web API using HTTPS - Invalid X509 certificate

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm unable to wire up bare ASP.NET Core Web API using HTTPS and Docker Compose version of Prometheus.

Prometheus returns:

> Get "https://host.docker.internal:443/metrics": x509: certificate is valid for localhost, not host.docker.internal

How do I create a valid certificate? How do I copy the certificate in the docker container?

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseUrls("https://*:443", "http://*:80");

// Depends on the following packages:
// - prometheus-net.AspNetCore
// - prometheus-net.Contrib
services.AddPrometheusCounters();
services.AddPrometheusAspNetCoreMetrics();
services.AddPrometheusHttpClientMetrics();
services.AddPrometheusSqlClientMetrics();

var app = builder.Build();

// TODO: Fix certificate
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapMetrics();

app.Run();
```

### prometheus.yml

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['prometheus:9090']
  
  - job_name: qs
    metrics_path: /metrics
    scheme: https
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:443']
```

### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.9'
name: qs

services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/provisioning/datasources.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasources.yaml
      - ./grafana/provisioning/dashboards.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboards.yaml
      - ./grafana/dashboards:/var/lib/grafana/dashboards
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=123456
      - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
    networks:
      - qs

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    networks:
      - qs

networks:
  qs:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For development mode you can skip certificate validation. You need to add `insecure_skip_verify: true`
Please see Prometheus [tls_config sections docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#tls_config)

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['prometheus:9090']
  
  - job_name: qs
    metrics_path: /metrics
    scheme: https
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true 
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:443']
```